# web-pack-dev server not auto refreshing the content on browser

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am beginner on npm and web-pack-dev server. Recently I have created reactJs app using nmp and webpack. So at the beginning everything gonna fine when I save the content it auto refresh and reload the content on browser. But on next day, after restarting server and change the content the server does not reloading the content. Every time I need to stop and start the server to see the changes. Which is not good. I have fix the problem by uninstall and install the webpack and webpack-dev-server. But today I again I do the same but the problem did not fixed. Anyone please suggested me how to fix this issue. I have created the app with the reference http://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm

Comment: Could you please post your webpack.config?

Comment: Without a webpack config file or some package.json where you run the dev server from, no one can help unfortunately. Please give us the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed by adding the line above to the webpack.config.js file, 
**var webpack = require('webpack')**, need to require the webpack package.